# The requested url not found error in codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I have created a login page using codeigniter framework.it works well.
After install apachi,mySql and php again my website login is not working.
I can go to `"http://localhost/test/"` and login button is there.
After The requested URL /test/user/user/login was not found on this server.When I click the login button redirect to the page `"http://localhost/test/user/user/login"` and it says "The requested URL /test/user/user/login was not found on this server"
How can I solve this?
It works well before I format the computer and install php again.

Comment: Did you enabled mod_rewrite?

Comment: Do you ask about "RewriteEngine on" in .htaccess file inside the project folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sloved after changing AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All in  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default .

Answer (score 2):

I have had a lot of problems trying to fix this issue and finally I have figured out that without changing index.php field within the config.php file, you have to specify the address like this; http://localhost/codeigniter_folder_name/index.php?/controller_name

This has solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess file maybe inside the application folder. Move it outside the application folder, also ensure to re-write the .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you have used user twice like *`http://localhost/test/user/user/login`*. Here, user is the name of the controller. So the url should be like *`http://localhost/test/user/login`*. If you are not using htaccess file ie, mod_rewrite is not enabled, then the url should be like *`http://localhost/test/index.php/user/login`*

Comment: I can access the login page without index.php.The error comes after click the login button.